# Initializing an array of pair in C++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, stl

I want to initialize an array of pair in the following way:

```
pair<int, int> adjs[4] = {{current_node.first-1, current_node.second}, {current_node.first+1, current_node.second}, {current_node.first, current_node.second-1}, {current_node.first, current_node.second+1}};
```

However my compiler, Code::Blocks 12.1, keeps on throwing the error:

```
brace-enclosed initializer used to initialize `std::pair<int, int>'|
```

I used this method once before on an online compiler and it worked. So is it the problem with the compiler or some syntax issue in my code?
I don't want to initialize 4 pair one by one. Suggest a way in which I can get rid of this error.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This universal initialization syntax is a C++11 feature, likely the compiler you are using does not support C++11 but the online one did.

You can initialize your array like this instead:

```
pair<int, int> adjs[4] = {make_pair(current_node.first-1, current_node.second), ...};
```

A live example: http://ideone.com/ggpGX9